# Spigot-API get another world into an World object in java

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I know how to get the main world into a World object.

```
World world = Bukkit.getWorld("world");
```

This would be the default world where players can build on.
I have a little mini game plugin and I want to tp the participating players into a game world.
I tried getting the other world like you can see above but that gives me an null error.

```
World world = Bukkit.getWorld("gameworld");
```

How do I manage to do this? And does it have something to do with the world container "worlds" where I can but additional worlds in?
Please help, ty

Comment: The second World would be world2 or something like that of course...

Comment: Try using Bukkit.createWorld() to create a new world, and then use your code to access it.

Comment: That would work, thank you but what if I have an existing world that I want to use?
Like I have a special world that I copied into the root server folder

Comment: Then bukkit should be able to detect and load it when you call getWorld.

Comment: Like I said, it would give me an error. I fixed this myself loading the world in the onEnable Method in the Main class so if I want to teleport a player to the "gameworld" the server knows it's there and the world is loaded.

Comment: So how exactly can I mark an answer as usefull or the solving answer and how can I close this post or set it to [solved] ? :D

Comment: These are only comments, they cannot be accepted as answers. If you just want to show they are helpful, you can upvote them. I'll also write the useful information in an answer, then you can click on the green checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a new world, use `Bukkit.createWorld()`.
To load it, you have to call `Bukkit.getWorld("name")` in the `onEnable()` method of your plugin to load it (or you can call the `Bukkit.createWorld()`, since that only creates a new world if it doesn't exist yet, and also provides a `World` object).